# Could not upload image using Parse Server and Android

Tags: android, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-android-sdk

I have error after migration to Parse Server with image upload: "Invalid file upload".

Use android-parse 1.13.1 and parse-server 2.3.2.

Adding Content-Type "image/png" to new ParseFile do not solve problem.

Code:

```
private ParseFile getParseFile(Bitmap file, String filename) {
        // Convert it to byte
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
        file.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
        return new ParseFile(filename, image, "image/png");
    }

ParseFile squarePhotoFile = getParseFile(squarePhoto, "square_photo.png");
squarePhoto.recycle();
squarePhotoFile.saveInBackground(new SaveInBackgroundSquarePhotoCallback(squarePhotoFile));
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, part of my code was bad:

```
ParseFile squarePhotoFile = new ParseFile("empty", new byte[]{});
squarePhotoFile.saveInBackground(new SaveInBackgroundSquarePhotoCallback(squarePhotoFile));
```

After not sending empty byte array to server, problem was solved.